# Reflections Library to Find All Classes within a Package

Tags: java, reflection, classpath, reflections

I am using the below code to find all of the Classes within a given package name. This works fine when the code is placed directly into my project. However, calling the service from a Commons Jar I put together isn't returning the data from my project. Can this be achieved? I am using org.reflection.Reflections library.

```
public Set<Class<?>> reflectPackage(String packageName){
    List<ClassLoader> classLoadersList = new LinkedList<ClassLoader>();
    classLoadersList.add(ClasspathHelper.contextClassLoader());
    classLoadersList.add(ClasspathHelper.staticClassLoader());

    Reflections reflections = new Reflections(
                              new ConfigurationBuilder().setScanners(
                              new SubTypesScanner(false), 
                              new ResourcesScanner()).setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader(classLoadersList.toArray(
                              new ClassLoader[0]))).filterInputsBy(
                              new FilterBuilder().include(FilterBuilder.prefix(packageName))));

    return reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
}
```

---

```
Project Structure 

Eclipse --- Security Base // Project
        |     |
        |     --- reflectPackage("com.app.controller") call
        |         // Note: this package is within this project, not the Commons project.
        | 
        --- Commons // Project
             |
             --- Reflector // Class
                 |
                 --- reflectPackage // Method
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used [Fast Classpath Scanner](https://github.com/lukehutch/fast-classpath-scanner) in one of our projects and found it really useful. It has a lot of useful functionalities when it comes to class path scanning. An example is shown below which will give information about classes inside a package. It will scan and find packages/classes even if they are part of a third party jar.

```
public Set<Class<?>> reflectPackage(String packageName) {
    final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
    new FastClasspathScanner("your.package.name")
       .matchAllClasses(new ClassMatchProcessor() {

        @Override
        public void processMatch(Class<?> klass) {
            classes.add(klass);
        }
    }).scan();
    return classes;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfect for me and is a lot less code than the previous solution.